# Google Chrome touch scrolling not working after short while

Tags: google-chrome, lenovo-laptop

I'm using the latest version of google chrome on a yoga book on windiws 10 and have the following problem: when I launch google chrome after a short while touch screen functions stop working correctly. It is as if the right mouse button was clicked as tapping on links only opens a context menu and scrolling does not work anymore. It has to be a software issue, most likely a chrom bug  as only chrome is affected and all functions always work well for around one minute.